# Ghostscript renders embedded fonts in pdf poorly (all jaggy)

Tags: pdf, fonts, embedded, rendering, ghostscript

Ghostscript doesn't render embedded fonts in pdf's properly. e.g. http://vegro.nl/cmsfiles/ConsumentenAssortiment/Brochure/10.axd The characters of the logo on the right top ('Thermrad') are all jagged. If I open the file in Adobe Reader, no problem at all!

Do you have this problem too? Is there any solution? I've been searching for days now, but I cannot find anything..

I tried Ghostscript 8.64 and 8.71 both on Windows Vista and CentOS.

Thank you so much! Dave

Comment: This Q cross posted and answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494377/ghostscript-renders-embedded-fonts-in-pdf-poorly-all-jaggy

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the file you linked to. The logo with the 'Themrad' string renders just fine with the latest version of Ghostscript (9.02).

But then, the PDF file may be a new version also ... its metadata say it was created on March 18, 2011 (but your question is from August 16, 2010).

This version of the PDF has embedded all the fonts used (different faces of *HelveticaNeue*).

Font embedding may not have been employed with a previous version of the file, which would explain some rendering problems because Ghostscript would have needed to substitute the original (unembedded) font in order to be able to render the file ***at all***...